# Error: Failed dependencies: perl(Date::Parse)

Tags: linux, perl

I have two different perl versions installed on my setup. One is default linux perl and other one is VRTSperl.

I am trying to install an rpm package and it is giving following error

**error: Failed dependencies:
perl(Date::Parse) is needed by xyz.rpm**

I have checked Parse.pm module is present in VRTSperl not in the default os perl.

So i have setup VRTSperl to my default perl but still getting same error.

Is there an issue with rpm that forcefully uses local os perl?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing: perl-DateTime-Format-Natural rpm.

Install it using yum or download rpm from rpm.pbone.net for your OS and install.